# How to dynmically set instance variable through a loop?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, braintree

I want to have have multiple braintree drop-in's on one page depending on the subscription plan a User chooses.  I want to be able to have the drop-in appear depending on which is clicked.  I'm having trouble attempting how to achieve multiple drop ins on one page without settings the tokens in advance.  I tried creating an on-click event function but not sure if I am doing it correctly.

I attempted:

```
<% @plans.map do |plan| %>
  <button onclick='braintreeClick()-<%= "#{plan.id}" %>'... > Click </button>
...
<% end %>
<script>
function braintreeClick-<%= plan.id %>() {
  var client_token = "<%= @client_token %>";
  ...
}
</script>
```

I can have multiple forms on a page if I set multiple tokens from the controller.

I tried a few different ways the other night but all failed such as:

```
@plans.map do |plan|
  @client_token_"#{plan.id}" = gateway.client_token.generate
end
```

and setting the token:

```
var client_token = "<%= @client_token_"#{plan.id}" %>";
```

This breaks my app with Error: `unexpected '='` in the controller for the line above

Tried a few other ways such as:

```
@client_token(plan.id)
```

Error: `unexpected '('`

Is there any way to dynamically set my instance variable or even a better way at achieving my javascript without hard coding the javascript and client_token?

I want to be able to dynamically set this in the case of where subscription plans are removed or added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways, how to do this:

The first one is using ruby methods: `instance_variable_set` and `instance_variable_get`:

```rb
# set new instance variable
instance_variable_set("@client_token_#{plan.id}", gateway.client_token.generate)

# read the instance variable
instance_variable_get("@client_token_#{plan.id}")
```

---

You could also use hash, instead of instance variables and it would probably be better

```rb
client_tokens = {}
@plans.map do |plan|
  client_tokens[plan.id] = gateway.client_token.generate
end

# and than read it with
client_tokens[plan.id]
```

If you want it accessible from more places than directly in the view, you can define it as the instance variable `@client_tokens = {}`

---

If you would like to change it to completely JS thing. you could do something like this:

```
<% @plans.map do |plan| %>
  <button onclick='braintreeClick("<%= gateway.client_token.generate %>")'... > Click </button>
...
<% end %>
<script>
function braintreeClick(client_token) {
  ...
}
</script>
```

You would generate token and put it directly to `braintreeClick` function call, now you don't have to bother with instance variables or more ruby code at all. This is better solution than the previous two.

---

The best solution would probably be to use unobtrusive javascript call. I don't know what JS framework you use, so I will demonstrate it with the jQuery:

```
<% @plans.map do |plan| %>
  <button class="js-brain-tree-button" data-client-token="<%= gateway.client_token.generate %>" ... > Click </button>
...
<% end %>
<script>
function braintreeClick(e) {
  var $button = $(e.currentTarget);
  var client_token = $button.data("client-token");
  ...
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-brain-tree-button").on('click', braintreeClick);
});
</script>
```

*Note: sorry if there are some typos or errors, I didn't test the code, but it should show the concept*

Comment: Why do you believe using the hashes would be a better approach? jw

Comment: Hash approach is about 8 times faster, but mostly - it is less magical, more strait-forward and readable. If you want to get back all of your tokens, you don't have to iterate over all of your `@plans` again, but you can just look into one hash. It just seems unnecessary to use instance variable magic to solve what you need... But I still think the best solutions for you would be the javascript ones. At the end it would be much less code (mostly in javascript - only one `braintreeClick` function for processing all of your `@plans`)

Comment: This all worked in getting me dynamic tokens like I wanted.  But I couldn't get the payment_method_nonce for all 3 (forms I ahve from `@plans` loop) to work.  The nonce would only work for the first form.  ended up just taking plan_token that I neeeded to the next page and using gthe payment form there

Answer (score 1):

What you look for are [instance_variable_set](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set) and analogical `instance_variable_get` methods.

In your case setting would be:

```
@plans.each do |plan|
  instance_variable_set("@client_token_#{plan.id}", gateway.client_token.generate
end
```

and then you read this:

```
var client_token = "<%= instance_variable_get("@client_token_#{plan.id}" %>";
```